# Waiting on jQuery AJAX calls to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an upload button that when clicking calls an ajax function to upload document.  Once that function runs I call another ajax function to refresh a table on screen displaying all my documents.  I have been looking at this question - [Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done)

which would seem to be what I need.  However I am un-sure how to implement for my current code.  I have:

```
$("#UploadButton").on('click', function () {
           doUpload(); // My First AJAX function
           refreshTable(); // My Second AJAX Function
       });
```

My `doUpload` AJAX function is as below:

```
function doUpload() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myupload url',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData($('#uploadForm')[0]),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function () {
                $.growlUI('Document Uploaded Sucessfully');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
```

My `refreshTable` ajax function then is:

```
function refreshTable() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url to get all files',
        type: 'GET',
        data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
        success: function (data) { populateTable(data); },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError); }
    });
    return false;
}
```

If I upload a document with current solution the success function of `refreshTable` seems to get hit too quickly and it doesn't have the find the most recent file uploaded.  I had tried to add the call to `refreshTable()` in the success function of my `doUpload` with a `setTimeout` of 5 seconds and sometimes this was working and refreshing the table but other times it wasn't uploading the table.

I then changed the click handler on the button to the below to attempt to have the functionality the other StackOverflow answer I linked to above has but this isn't working either

```
$("#UploadButton").on('click', function () {
            $.when(doUpload()).done(function() {
               refreshTable();                
             });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callback mechanism.

```
function doUpload(callback) {
    $.ajax({ //some parameters
        success: function (data) {
            //do some work here
            callback();
        }
    );
}
```

Then you can call the function chain as:

```
doUpload(refreshTable);
```

Comment: The callback seems to be working but the refresh table function still is getting hit to early to pick up the newly uploaded file - is there anyway I could add an extra delay before the callback is executed?

Comment: there is `setTimeout` function in JS, but the code I provided should work for you. Are you sure you didn't add the `()` of `refreshTable`?

Comment: @TheRiddler, [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wptv9x2v/1/) works as it should be. Can you feed me with a fiddle?

Answer (score -1):

EDIT : @qamyoncu answers is better than mine.

In AJAX, calls are done async. that's why you don't get what you want.

Here is a tricky solution to avoid the problem you have:

```
function doUpload(init) {
        var res = null;
        var _init = init || false;

        if (!_init) {
            _init = true;
            $.ajax({
                /// ajax call for doUpload()...
            });
        }

        if (res == null) {
            setTimeout(function(){ doUpload(_init); }, 100);
        } else {
            refreshTable();
        }
    }
```